# Background not displaying in Android project

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to add a gradient as a background into my Android app. I started by creating a **drawable** directory in my **src** directory and created a **gradient.xml** file

[image]

### gradient.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0000ff"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

And I also created a **background.xml** file

### background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#EEEEEE" />
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="20dp"
            android:right="10dp" android:bottom="20dp" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in my **activity_main.xml** file I added an image view and added the gradient as a background

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The background is
 android:background="@drawable/gradient"

but the image view does not have a size. If you use the background.xml as background it should show up. Or specify a size for the image view rather than using wrap_content

Comment: You have a great point. OK so what happened is that this author of the book I am following along to was not very clear. I apparently needed to add the gradient to the `<RelativeLayout>` not to the `<ImageView>` that I did not even need.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I needed to apply the gradient to the **RelativeLayout**.

Once I did that I could see the background. Unfortunately that image view was a bad idea and I did not need it. Here is what ended up working for me.

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in ur imageview, use height and width as some value. for ex 200dps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a selector may help u :

gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape>
          <gradient
             android:angle="90"
             android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
             android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
             android:type="linear" />
       </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```